# Get human message from jquery $.get fail error handler

Tags: jquery

I have the error respond from Python server.

```
result = { 'message' : 'acceptable api request is https://insider.jstock.co/api/{APIKEY}?symbol={SYMBOL}' }
result_json = json.dumps(result)
return Response(result_json, status=404, mimetype='application/json')
```

I try to catch the error message

```
$.get( "https://insider.jstock.co/api/775048015894426281702bf21e8bd965?symbol=" + encodeURI(symbol) + '&count=100', function( data ) {
    $( "#mycode" ).html( data );
}, 'text')
.fail(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // XMLHttpRequest.status = 404
    // XMLHttpRequest.statusText = Not Found
    // errorThrown = Not Found
});
```

I'm interested in getting message "acceptable api request is..."

May I know how I can do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the **[javascript popup boxes](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp)**

Sample:

```
$.get( "https://insider.jstock.co/api/775048015894426281702bf21e8bd965?symbol=" + encodeURI(symbol) + '&count=100', function( data ) {
    $( "#mycode" ).html( data );
}, 'text')
.fail(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    var data = JSON.parse(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    alert(data.message);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.get` is a shorthand for `$.ajax`. The documentation for that method is here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ .

That page says " a jqXHR object will expose the following properties and methods:"....of which `responseText` is one property. Again as per the docs, your `XMLHttpRequest` callback variable is a `jqXHR` type of object (basic a jQuery extended version of the native XHR object).

So, you can get the responseText property and parse it as JSON and you can then access the "message" property:

```
.fail(function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    var response = JSON.parse(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    alert(response.message);
});
```